# Open interval sequences of functions question

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

> Investigate the convergence of $f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{nx}{nx+1}, 0<x<1.$

---

**By attempt:**

I take the limit of the function in order to investigate its pointwise convergence:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_{n}(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{nx}{nx+1} = 1$$

Since $0$ and $1$ are not involved in the interval I did not check those bounds.

And I tried to find a $n$ such that $n>N$, for $\varepsilon>0$

So,

$$\left|\dfrac{nx}{nx+1}-1\right|=\left|\dfrac{1}{nx+1}\right|$$

And I looked the graph of the function it seemed to be uniformly convergent:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For any epsilon greater than zero and fixed $n$, choose $X=\frac{1}{2n}$, then $f(X)=\frac{1}{1+2}=\frac{1}{3}$, so fails to be uniformly convergent on any open interval with 0 as a limit point. If this is what the question was asking(it is not clear).

Comment: Yes that was the question but how we choosed the $x=\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: @beingmathematician What does uniform convergence mean to you?

Comment: Uniform convergence of a sequence of function is related to its graph. And we wish the graph of the function must stay in some $x+\varepsilon$ and $x-\varepsilon$ interval

Comment: @beingmathematician I would not say it is related to the graph. The definition is the same idea as the difference between uniform continuity and continuity. For all epsilon greater than zero and for all $n$ larger than some $N$, it must be that for all $x$ in the interval, $|f_n-f|\lt \epsilon$. This is simply the definition.